# Need to join multiple (Apache) server logs into one chronological log

Tags: apache, parsing, indexing, merge, logging

Apache log in long format, stored on multiple servers, relating to the same domain. I need to merge them together in chronological order so AWstats or something similar can create a log.

Of course, telling me how to just throw them randomly at a parsing tool to generate an access log would be a sufficient answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#LOADLOG

AWstats includes a script to do this. For people running load balancers and multiple app servers, AWstats just kind of handles it for you. It's quite cool.